# What is the 'Associated Entity' in a CiviVolunteer Project?

Tags: civivolunteer

I'm using CiviCM version 5.18.3 with Drupal 7.67 . I've installed CiviVolunteer.

At `~/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/manage` I see a test Project I have created in a list. In that row, next to Volunteer Project is a column named `Associated Entity`. The `Associated Entity` has a value of `--`.

I have related the Project to a Campaign, and the Project has an Owner, a Manager, and a Beneficiary.

So what value should be listed under `Associated Entity`?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently `Associated Entity` means `Associated Event`, if and when a volunteer Project is created as part of an Event. I've created an [Issue](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/issues/527) to change `Associated Entity` to just `Event`.